# Bulk re assigment of relationships

Tags: import, relationships

If you have a large number of contacts managed by one 'volunteer rep' as a relationship, when that rep leaves then there is a lot of cumbersome manual data entry.

I have looked and I can't find any built in reassigment function.

All I have worked out is as potential approaches
1.  user heavy  - run the relationship report - download a csv, change something and import
2. do it in the database directly

both not really satisfactory

Any ideas / approaches / am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

More of a thought than an answer (and really off the top of my head) - try using the Merge Contacts option, have the person with existing Relationships on the left, newbie on the right, untick all boxes other than Relationships, Merge.

Revisit your 'deleted' contact and undelete them - does it restore the relationships to them (I don't think so). Does this achieve what you need? Pls report back.

Comment: Good call, that works in theory - will let you know in practice

Comment: Actually for what we want. merge isn't even necessary. merge deletes the original - so might was well just edit the name / contact of the rep to anew person  ( an recreate the old person if they still need to be in the system

Comment: indeed you can of course just change person X to be new person X1.